# <UNKNOWN> value for host in snmptraps

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, snmptrapd

while executing

"**snmptrap -v 1 -c public localhost TRAP-TEST-MIB::demotraps localhost 4 0 '' IF-MIB::ifIndex i 1"**

on my system,I am getting host ,ip & OID values as

**host = localhost.localdomain :ip = UDP: [127.0.0.1]:49109->[127.0.0.1] :OID =DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance 0:3:12:38.28**

But when traps are coming from outside its showing

**host = :ip = UDP: [192.168.1.73]:52346->[192.168.1.23]:OID =DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance 7:1:05:54.27** .

Now its clearly shown above that host value didn't     show up ...I want to know why & how it get to be resolve.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply keep ip & its corresponding host-name in /etc/hosts file..That's All
My /etc/hosts file is-

```
127.0.0.1     localhost.localdomain localhost
::1       localhost6.localdomain6   localhost6
192.168.1.150    ZYXEL
192.168.1.73   CISCO
192.168.1.135 DIGISOL
```

Answer (score 0):

the one reason is if you are using VMware/virtual OS and you have not configured different IP than your host machine IP.

Comment: No I am not using any VMware/virtual OS

Comment: have you checked sender IP ? and which OS you are using ?

Comment: Linux Fedora 14...yes ..actually senders Ip has been keep coming but host address displayed as UNKNOWN

Comment: This issue has been fixed in 5.4.x SVN branch.  rather it you can check  edit connections-> ipv4 settings that the IPs are written properly or not.. 3rd option is you can try different "snmptrapd" binary

Comment: Sorry for being late....How I can use that 5.4.x SVN branch.means updation ,I dont have any idea